# Fixing an element inside the scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

The `.parent` div has `overflow: scroll` and the `.child` has `position: fixed`. I'd like to scroll the content of the `.parent` div while preserving the `.child`'s position inside it.

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 900px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.child {    
  background: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;    
  height: 100px;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  parent
  <div class="child">
    child
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, here's a reply with several different languages: Python. Java. C#... And because you asked for them specifically, there's CSS and JavaScript as well. Now what was your question?

Comment: It's unclear... what you want to do, because your child is already fixed (you missed `top left ...` attributes), so it's already not scrolling if you scroll the parent.

Comment: let me explain what i m trying to do...i created a parent div with scroll in which i added a child class which should stay fixed during my scroll of parent div but if ill use position:fixed  with child it will become fixed while i scroll my entire page...if i use position:absolute with child it will still scroll with my page

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
height:500px;
width:500px;
overflow:scroll;
position:absolute;
background:black;
}


.child {

position: sticky;
top:0;
height:80px;
width:500px;
background-color: #cae8ca;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent" >
<div class = "child"  >
chi
</div>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: i just used too many <hr> and <br> tags but this works perfectly for now. it uses a position sticky inside a scrolling class on the top.